# How to set a different expiration times for multiple records in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table where I want each row to have a specific expiration time, how to do that with MySQL?

Comment: What do you mean?  MySQL doesn't have native support for anything caled "expiration time".

Comment: yes I know that, but I'm trying to do this on one of my tables is there any way to do something similar to this.

Comment: Data model, example, something more than a 1 liner.